# Callback 'magic' in master detail flow

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

The Eclipse generated master detail flow has some callback magic in the class which extends `ListFragment` - I say magic because that's what it looks like when you are an Android and a Java noob, all at once :)

Given the code below can someone answer a few questions for me:

1. What does the `onAttach` method of the `ListFragment` do with `mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity`?
2. Which `onItemSelected` method is called in `onListItemClick` method of `ListFragment`, the one which needs implementation or `onItemSelected` in `FragmentActivity`?
3. All these `onItemSelected` methods take an `id` of type `String` (because `DummyContent` `id` is a `String`). If I changed `DummyContent` `id` to a `long`, which `onItemSelected` methods would I need to change? I tried changing the one in `FragmentActivity` but this has `@Override` so I wasn't allowed to :(

Thank you

```
public class RecordingListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

    public interface Callbacks {

        public void onItemSelected(String id);
    }

    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        // NEEDS IMPLEMENTATION - i guess????
        public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        }
    };

...

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }

...

}
```

And one more file...

```
public class RecordingListActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements RecordingListFragment.Callbacks {

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording_list);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        if (findViewById(R.id.recording_detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
            ((RecordingListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.recording_list))
                    .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(RecordingDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            RecordingDetailFragment fragment = new RecordingDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.recording_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, RecordingDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(RecordingDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the onAttach method of the ListFragment do with mCallbacks =
>   (Callbacks) activity?

In the `onAttach` callback the `Activity`/`FragmentActivity`(to which the `Fragment` will be tied/used) is passed to that `Fragment` instance(through the *activity* parameter). That line simply casts that `Activity` to the `Callbacks` interface to later be used in the `Fragment`(see below). Your `Activity` **must** implement that interface otherwise the code will fail due to the previous `if` condition. Basically, the code in the `onAttach` method says: *"The Activity where this fragment will be used must implement the Callbacks interface otherwise the code will fail with an IllegalStateException"*.

> Which onItemSelected method is called in onListItemClick method of
>   ListFragment, the one which needs implementation or onItemSelected in
>   FragmentActivity?

In a very raw explanation: The `RecordingListFragment` keeps a reference(the *mCallbacks* field) to a `Callbacks` type object(meaning a class which implements the `Callbacks` interface). Initially, to this `Callabacks` reference the code will assign a default/empty `Callbacks` reference(*sDummyCallbacks*) which doesn't do anything(so no, you don't have to provide some implementation for the `sDummyCallbacks`) as its *onItemSelected* is empty, this is to avoid a possible `NullPointerException` in some cases(for example, if you don't assign something to the `mCallbacks` field and you call `onItemSelected` on it). When the `onAttach` method is run the reference to the `Activity` where this `Fragment` will exist will be cast to a `Callbaks` and put in the `mCallbacks` field. After this happens, when you call `mCallbacks.onItemSelected()` the `FragmentActivity`'s `onItemSelected` method will be called and the code from the method will be run. If at a later point the `onDetach` is called, the `mCallbacks` will once again point to the `sDummyCallbacks`, after this happens, calling `mCallbacks.onItemSelected()` will do nothing.

The interface system above is important because it will make your `RecordingListFragment` a much more reusable component in your code as it will not be tied to a specific `Activity` implementation. When the user clicks an item in your fragment's list you'll call the `onItemSelected` on the `mCallbacks` reference to run the `onItemSelected` method from that object(the Activity in your case). Your fragment doesn't know how implements the interface and it doesn't even care. Think, for example that you have three activities and each one uses a `RecordingListFragment` fragment. How you would need to change the `RecordingListFragment` class to make it work with the three activities where it will be used?

> All these onItemSelected methods take an id of type String (because
>   DummyContent id is a String). If I changed DummyContent id to a long,
>   which onItemSelected methods would I need to change? I tried changing
>   the one in FragmentActivity but this has @Override so I wasn't allowed
>   to :(

Modify the interface:

```
public interface Callbacks {

        public void onItemSelected(long id);
}
```

If you save the java file Eclipse will complain(that you must override a superclass method) where this interface was implemented. For the `sDummyCallbacks`:

```
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    // NEEDS IMPLEMENTATION - i guess???? <- it doesn't need no implementation
    // it's purpose is to do nothing
    public void onItemSelected(long id) {
    }
};
```

Also the `FragmentActivity` implements the `Callbacks` interface so you need to change that too:

```
public class RecordingListActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements RecordingListFragment.Callbacks {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(long id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
    // ...
```

finally you would use the `mCallbacks` in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {     
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(id);
}
```

I would recommend that you take some time to study a bit about the java language, so you'll work to understand the Android code and not the Android code + the java way.