# Fragment inside Fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was changing a Activity to a Fragment to use inside a Scrollable Tab Activity. But I getting this exception I load this fragment:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
  at com.zhensydow.demo.MainMenuFragment.onCreateView(MainMenuFragment.java:43)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
    ....
```

And the used (simplified) xml loaded is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >
  <fragment   <<---- LINE #17
    android:id="@+id/mlist"
    android:name="com.zhensydow.demo.MListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/mcontent" />

    <FrameLayout ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

The error is caused in this code:

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment implements
        MenuListFragment.Callbacks {

    // ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_main_menu, container, false);

        return ll;
    }

    // ...

}
```

The error is on a fragment, I think it's caused because the old activity loaded two fragments inside him.

How can I solve it?

UPDATE: added full fragmen xml data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your Fragment contains some code like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557930/callback-magic-in-master-detail-flow), requiring your Activity to implement a callback interface, and your Activity does not implement that interface.

Comment: You're rigth, i move the callback from fragment to swipe_entity, and it works

Answer (score 0):

A `fragment` tag is required to have both a name and an id.

Comment: The fragmen has name and id, I added the full fragment tag used.

Comment: In that case, post some more from the logcat.  There should be one or more "caused by" sections.

Comment: No, in the logcat.  If you scroll down from the InflateException it should have a "caused by SomeOtherException" etc.

Comment: I found this:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.